# Отслеживание состояния переменной

Tags: c#, unity3d

Нужно отслеживать состояние переменной.
Пытался сделать такой код:

```
private static Dictionary<bool, bool> conditions = new Dictionary<bool, bool>();

public static bool Is(bool Is) {
    bool IsOld;
    if (!conditions.TryGetValue(Is, out IsOld)) {
        IsOld = false;
    }
    conditions[Is] = Is;
    if (Is && !IsOld) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Нужно чтобы этот метод работал единожды когда изменяется значение переменной.
Как такое сделать?
То есть была переменная `true` метод сказал `true` и после уже говорил `false`.
Стала переменная `false` метод глянул, сказал `true` и снова стал `false`.
Помогите разобраться, что я не так делаю?

Как это правильно сделать, для любой переменной, которую закидываем в `Is(variable)`.

Что никто не знает как это сделать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вообщем, все банально и просто:

```
public static bool Is(bool Is, int key = 0) {
    if (conditions.ContainsKey(key)) {
        if (conditions[key] != Is) {
            conditions[key] = Is;
            return true;
        }
    } else {
        conditions[key] = Is;
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Остается лишь делать каждому новому вызову, новый ключ:

```
Is(var1);
Is(var2, 1);
........
```

Для прешедствующих версий нета, юзаем смело `[CallerLineNumber] int Line = 0` или еще есть фишка `nameof(var)`,  сам нэймуф можем не использовать в прототипе, а прямо внутрях метода юзать, для вызова, даже без определения самого прототипа, прямо в теле метода определяем стрингу и вуаля:

```
 string IsName = nameof(Is);
```

Comment: замените тип ключа на `string` и при вызове используйте `Is(var, nameof(var))` - не придется запоминать ключи для вызова, да и в режиме отладки содержимое кэша нагляднее. Преимущество перед передачей имени захардкоженным строковым литералом - если переименовать переменную средствами IDE, то не придется привить эти самые литералы по всем вызовам.

Comment: @rdom, я согласился бы, но увы, в Unity это может быть поддержкой только с `#net4`, в  `#2.0-Standard` этого нет, можно было бы просто вообще сделать `[CallerLineNumber]` и не париться с написанием 2 аргумента.

Comment: Так `nameof` это же фишка времени компиляции, там по факту будет все тот-же простой строковый литерал, ни какой специальной поддержки не требуется

Comment: @rdom, не поддерживается в `Unity` проектах на `Net 2.0 Standard`, а юзать `Net 4+` не всегда хорошо, раздует проект. Даже в рекомендациях, сами юниразрабы говорят, если проект не сильно специфический лучше воздержаться от `Net 4+`, А так добавил, для заметки.

Comment: А какая версия языка там используется? не среды исполнения а именно языка? я правильно понимаю, что `nameof` не понимает компилятор? Потому что в студии для Standard 2.0 ограничений на эту конструкцию нет.

Comment: @rdorn, если память не изменяет `4.0`, а `nameof` появился в `6.0`. Не ну конечно - это можно и поднять. все это дело и сделать хоть `7+`, но тут дело каждого конечно-же. но в проект добавится куча библиотек и т.д... Не очень удобно будет.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/100886/discussion-between-rdorn-and-and).